# Inheritance or composition on gui objects

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I am developing a simple game. I created a `Maze` class which contains methods and algorithms for creating / modifying / solving mazes. I also created a `GraphicalMaze` class, which should only contain a `paint` method to draw the maze on a `JPanel`.

At this point, i have to decide if:

- `GraphicalMaze` should extends `Maze`, with a `JPanel` as member variable (inheritance)

or

- `GraphicalMaze` should extends `JPanel`, with `Maze` as member variable (composition)

This problem recurs every time i have to create 'gui' objects from 'abstract' ones.
I am interested in your opinions, and i want to understand what is the 'right' way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the easiest or most objective question to answer. There are some who tend to say you should favor composition over inheritance in most cases. I would say, think about your objects and how they ***really*** relate to each other. In this case, remember that inheritance represents an *is-a* relationship, whereas composition represents a *has-a*.

So, the question becomes, *is-a* GraphicalMaze a Maze? Or is it the *representation* of a maze? I would argue its the latter. Which of course means you would be using composition instead of Inheritance to represent it.

Comment: No it isn't :p My opinion is that the answer is the second one, but your question is very subtle...what do you think?

Comment: Composition, my friend. In this case it's an easy decision.

Answer (score 2):

If the only reason `GraphicalMaze` exists is to draw `Maze`, then the method should be included in the `Maze` class.  I usually call the method `draw`, but `paint` works.

You should only extend a `JComponent` when you want to override a method.  Otherwise, it's better to have the `JComponent` as a member variable.

Composition over inheritance.

In your particular case, I would extend `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method to call the `paint` method of your `Maze` class.  You would have to pass an instance of the `Maze` class to the extended `JPanel` class.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I also would extend JPanel as you said, but i don't agree that the draw method should be in the Maze class: i'm absolutely not a design expert, but in my opinion this would break the Single responsibility principle...what do you think?

Comment: Generally, when I'm creating a game, I have each object in the game draw itself.  To me, that's part of the object's responsibility.  As I said in the answer, by the time we get to the extended JPanel class, the paintComponent method calls a model draw method.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option number two. The reasoning being that GraphicalMaze is a class that modifies the display but the Maze contains the data to be displayed, so the GraphicalMaze should have a closer "connection" to the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I see your `GraphicalMaze` object as being a panel that displays a maze, and I suspect it would be easier to fit it into a graphical application by treating it as a subclass of `JPanel`. That being the case, my own solution would be to extend `JPanel` but call the new class something like `MazePanel` rather than `GraphicalMaze`.

Having said that, if you face this question often it would probably be worth the effort to try implementing it both ways and see which one leads you to an application structure that is easier to work with.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes i like MazePanel more than GraphicalMaze, english is not my native :p i think that the structure (at least for my simple projects) would remain roughly the same, it's only about the "correctness" of the code.